# Keras add data with Sequential layers

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have two sequential models in Keras:

```
def generator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(3, 100*100)))
    model.add(Dense(100*100))
    model.add(Reshape((1, 100, 100), input_shape=(100*100,)))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy');
    return model
```

and

```
def discriminator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(4, 100*100)))
    model.add(Dense(100*100))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy');
    return model
```

I also have a function to concatenate these models together. I am trying to train a generative adversarial network with both the generator and discriminator as lstm's. This is why I need the function

```
def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(generator)
    discriminator.trainable = False
    model.add(discriminator)
    return model
```

which I use to train the network using

```
g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(noise, [1] * BATCH_SIZE)
discriminator.trainable = True
print("batch %d g_loss : %f" % (index, g_loss))
```

In order for the last snippet of code for training to work, the generator and discriminator should be able to merge together. But, the output of my generator cannot be input into my discriminator because I need to add some data to the output of the generator before sending it into the discriminator. How can I do this in Keras so that the discriminator can be added onto the generator? Is there any way to add data in a `model.add` function? I could not find anything in the Keras documentation

Comment: What your additional data looks like?

Comment: I reshape the output of the generator into a 1x10000 matrix and then concatenate this with 3 other 1x10000 matrices. I then pass this obtained matrix and a label(either 1 or 0) into the discriminator to train it.

Comment: So is your `Reshape` shape set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    model = Sequential()
    list_of_dicriminator_inputs = [generator]

    for _ in range(3):
        auxiliary_model = Sequential()
        auxiliary_model.add(Reshape((1, 100*100), input_shape=(100 * 100,)))
        list_of_dicriminator_inputs.append(auxiliary_model)

    extended_generator_output = Merge(list_of_dicriminator_inputs,
                                      mode="concat",
                                      concat_axis=1)
    model.add(extended_generator_output)
    discriminator.trainable = False
    model.add(discriminator)
    return model
```

In order this to work you should change the this line of `generator` code:

```
model.add(Reshape((1, 100 * 100), input_shape=(100*100,)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please briefly explain your code? I am a little new to keras. Also, what should I change that line in the generator to?

Comment: `Merge` layers is taking list of 4 models and is concatenating them along first input axis which in your case is a 'timestep' dimension. Then it's fed to your `discriminator` model.

Comment: What should now be my input to `g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(noise, [1] * BATCH_SIZE)`? My present `noise` matrix is `BATCH_SIZEx4x10000` and an error comes up saying `The model expects 4 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (4, 10000)`

Comment: You should provide a list which consists of `[input_generator, mat1, mat2, mat3]` where each `mat` should have a shape `(nb_of_examples, 1, 100 * 100)` and `input_generator` should have shape `(nb_of_examples, 3, 100 * 100)`.

Comment: Ok. My generator will take the input_generator and generate an output. Let this output be Y. Then my discriminator will take mat1,mat2,mat3 and Y as input to it's LSTM in that order. Am I correct?

Comment: To preserve the above mentioned order, I think In need to put `list_of_dicriminator_inputs = [generator]` at the end. Am I correct?

Comment: Could you print out a `model.summary()`? Then we'll check that.

Comment: By nb_of_examples, do you mean BATCH_SIZE?

Comment: Good news! The model is working now. However, I need to concatenate the output of the generator at the end of the inputs. How do I do this? I have tried initializing `list_of_dicriminator_inputs = []` and putting `list_of_dicriminator_inputs.append([generator])` after the for loop in the `generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):` function. However, this results in the error: `line 1144, in _arguments_validation
    layer_output_shape = layer.get_output_shape_at(node_indices[i])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_output_shape_at' due to `concat_axis=1`
`

Comment: Because you are appending a list containing a generator not generator itself. Try `.. .append (generator)`